# Structure padding with zero length array

Tags: c

What is the best practice of using variable length array inside a structure?
Say

```
typedef struct foo_s {
   uint32_t data_type;
   uint16_t data_len;
   uint8_t  data[];
} foo_t;
```

On a x86_64 machine with Gcc 4.8, i got

```
sizeof(foo_t) == 8, but
offsetof(foo_t, data) == 6
```

looks like there is a difference there, no padding after data_len, but there is padding for the structure.
Should I keep always keep the largest member last to avoid this? i.e.

```
typedef struct foo_s {
   uint16_t data_len;
   uint32_t data_type;
   uint8_t  data[];
} foo_t;
```

What's the best practice for using var len array?

Comment: sizeof returns 8 because of the need to keep the uint32_t still aligned when the struct is an element of an array.  Of course you are **never** going to store them in an array, so just ignore that.  Your call to malloc only uses offsetof() + array size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a particular reason for wanting `data` to be 4-byte aligned (and if so, why is it a `uint8`?), the first one is mildly preferable because it'll save you a couple of bytes. For a variable-length structure like this, the value reported by `sizeof` is not really relevant, for exactly this reason. If you decide to allocate `sizeof(foo_t) + data_len` bytes for it then you'll be wasting a couple of bytes, but you'd waste them in padding in your second structure definition anyway.

Comment: yeah, i am not too worried about alignment, more about the whole size difference if users calculate the size in different ways, especially when there is an array of foo_t packed to a buffer.

Comment: If there's a whole array of them in a buffer, then you need to pad the allocations anyway, so there's even more reason to go with the first form.

Comment: could you elaborate more on "I need to pad the allocations"? Thank you.

Comment: If your architecture requires ints to be padded on four-byte boundaries, then you can't have (say) five bytes for the variable-length member and start the next struct at the next byte; you need to pad up the total size to something `int` can work with. Of course, it's pretty rare to see variable-length-array-having structures packed together, so this doesn't often come up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pack your structs without sacrificing alignment then yes: the best option is to order elements in decreasing or increasing order. The array must be the last element, so here your best option is decreasing order (note that the size win is small, and it only matters if you have a large array of structs, but with a flexible array member you can't have an array of structs).